# Nodejs Child Process: write to stdin from an already initialised process

Tags: node.js, stdin, phantomjs, external-process, child-process

I am trying to spawn an external process `phantomjs` using node's `child_process` and then send information to that process after it was initialized, is that possible?

I have the following code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('phantomjs');

child.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

child.stdin.write("console.log('Hello from PhantomJS')");
```

But the only thing I got on the stdout is the initial prompt for phantomjs console.

```
phantomjs>
```

So it seems the `child.stdin.write` is not making any effect.

I am  not sure I can send additional information to phantomjs ater the initial spawn.

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You need to pass also `\n` symbol to get your command work:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('phantomjs');

child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

child.stdin.write("console.log('Hello from PhantomJS')\n");

child.stdin.end(); /// this call seems necessary, at least with plain node.js executable
```

Comment: yes but why? or maybe a semicolon instead of a newline, also?

Comment: I added the child.stdin.end() call

Comment: @AlexanderMills CLRF `\r\n` since it's the line terminator that triggers `write` to pipe a new line. `child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);` is unnecessary actually.

Comment: The `child.stdin.end()` call is critical. Banged my head for a while until I found this. Thanks @AlexanderMills

Comment: @AlexanderMills child.stdin.end() isn't critical, In my case i need the process to stay open. And write as i need. to run some tts command (so it will be fast). And it work fine without child.stdin.end() [\r\n is the critical thing, which is well known] [I'm spawning powershell.exe, don't know about phanthomjs]. [How it's different for you ? How it's critical? ty]

Comment: adding stdin.end creates an infinite loop for me. in my case I want the process to wait for the next user input and stay open.

Comment: without child.stdin.end(); sometimes the child process sis not taking the input even with \r and ]n

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501287/macos-nodejs-open-the-terminal-by-passing-the-command-to-execute

Answer (score 5):

You need to surround your `write` by `cork` and `uncork`, the `uncork` method flushes all data buffered since `cork` was called. `child.stdin.end()` will flush data too, but no more data accepted.

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child = spawn('phantomjs');

child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

child.stdin.cork();
child.stdin.write("console.log('Hello from PhantomJS')\n");
child.stdin.uncork();
```

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501287/macos-nodejs-open-the-terminal-by-passing-the-command-to-execute