# Use child_process#spawn with a generic string

Tags: node.js, bash, zsh, child-process

I have a script in the form of a string that I would like to execute in a Node.js child process.

The data looks like this:

```
const script = {
    str: 'cd bar && fee fi fo fum',
    interpreter: 'zsh'
};
```

Normally, I could use

```
const exec = [script.str,'|',script.interpreter].join(' ');

const cp = require('child_process');
cp.exec(exec, function(err,stdout,sterr){});
```

however, `cp.exec` buffers the stdout/stderr, and I would like to be able to be able to stream stdout/stderr to wherever.

does anyone know if there is a way to use `cp.spawn` in some way with a `generic` string, in the same way you can use cp.exec? I would like to avoid writing the string to a temporary file and then executing the file with cp.spawn.

`cp.spawn` will work with a string but only if it has a predictable format - this is for a library so it needs to be extremely generic.

...I just thought of something, I am guessing the best way to do this is:

```
const n = cp.spawn(script.interpreter);
n.stdin.write(script.str);   // <<< key part

n.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

n.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./wherever'));
```

I will try that out, but maybe someone has a better idea.

downvoter: you are useless

Comment: omg the ridiculous downvote thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured this out.

I used the answer from this question:
[Nodejs Child Process: write to stdin from an already initialised process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230370/nodejs-child-process-write-to-stdin-from-an-already-initialised-process/13231002#comment69591333_13231002)

The following allows you to feed a generic string to a child process, with different shell interpreters, the following uses `zsh`, but you could use `bash` or `sh` or whatever executable really.

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const n = cp.spawn('zsh');

n.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
n.stdin.write('echo "bar"\n');   // <<< key part, you must use newline char

n.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

n.stdout.on('data', function(d){
    console.log('data => ', d);
});
```

Using Node.js, it's about the same, but seems like I need to use one extra call, that is, `n.stdin.end()`, like so:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const n = cp.spawn('node').on('error', function(e){
    console.error(e.stack || e);
});

n.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
n.stdin.write("\n console.log(require('util').inspect({zim:'zam'}));\n\n");   // <<< key part

n.stdin.end();   /// seems necessary to call .end()

n.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');

n.stdout.on('data', function(d){
    console.log('data => ', d);
});
```